SAS Viya - How to get and use the current file name?
I've got a bunch of programs in SAS Viya (at least 50), and am using the PRINTTO statement to save the logs to files, for later reference.
I would like to use the same statement, and have SAS Viya insert the file name and date.
I've got the date done, with automatic macro variables.
I've tried the methods in:
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p1ns5wvyfxbca8n1l3konj0yj6nq.htm,
https://support.sas.com/kb/24/301.html,
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p1ns5wvyfxbca8n1l3konj0yj6nq.htm and https://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/macro/z1071968.htm
They all do not work:
This    %put The current program is %sysfunc(getoption(sysin));
Yields: The current program is   84      85 
This:  %sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME);
Yields: WARNING: The argument to macro function %SYSGET is not defined as a system variable.
This: %put "Current program: &_SASPROGRAMFILE";
Yields: SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable _SASPROGRAMFILE resolves to  SYMBOLGEN:  Some characters in the above value which were subject to macro quoting have been unquoted for printing. "Current program: "
I'd appreciate any help that you might have.
Sincerely,
Barry

How did you submit the program to VIYA?  Are you using SAS/Studio? Something else?  Sounds like something created _SASPROGRAMFILE but just set it to an empty string.

I'm working in SAs Studio on Databricks.

Not sure how Databricks has anything to do with SAS/Studio.  SAS/Studio runs in a browser.  I don't think Databricks is a browser.  Does SAS/Studio know what file you are submitting?  Or did you just type or paste in some code into an unnamed editor window?  If so that might explain why it did not set any named into the _SASPROGRAMFILE macro variable when it sent the code to SAS to run.

There is an old thread on communities.sas.com that suggests you may not be able to get the info from Studio on Viya, unless you are doing a background submit.  https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Studio/how-do-I-know-the-name-of-the-program-running-in-SAS-Studio-SAS/td-p/724801  I would open a new session and try %PUT _ALL_; and also look in sashelp.vextfl, as mentioned in that thread.

In addition to exploring the information logged by %PUT _GLOBAL_, you can look at the information delivered by DICTIONARY.FILES (data _null_; set sashelp.vextfl; put _all_; run;  Unfortunately there is default built-in SAS feature that delivers all the system environment variables in play for a given session (you would need XCMD server privilege to use system command env and SYSGET() to retrieve).

The easiest way to solve this is to have each program be responsible for telling you what its name is.  So pick a macro variable name you want to use, say MYNAMEIS, and then add a %LET statement to top of each program file.  So if your program file is named fred.sas you might add the line:
%let mynameis=fred;

Then later on when you go to build your title or footnote or whatever you can reference that macro variable as &mynameis.

Thank you, everybody!  I'll look at the data dictionary (SAS has a lot of way it stores information!).  I would like to avoid having to manually set the name, but it might come down to that.
